# Alert Dialog Two Buttons

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hello all i have a simple problem i have a alertDialog and i want it to show two buttons i have searched here but it seems the options before don't work anymore and are deprecated.

Anyone know the new way of doing this you can see my code below that doesn't work.

```
  Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
    share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // call some other methods before that I guess...
             AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PasswActivity.this).create(); //Read Update
             alertDialog.setTitle("Uprgade");
             alertDialog.setMessage("Upgrade Text Here");

             alertDialog.setButton("Upgrade", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             });
                 alertDialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()    {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             });



             alertDialog.show();  //<-- See This!


    }
    });
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

try this

```
public void showDialog(Activity activity, String title, CharSequence message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

    if (title != null) builder.setTitle(title);

    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: do we need to declare the buttons as positive and negative? what if they're enither? just 2 different options? or maybe 3?

Comment: You can add NeutralButton - see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingButtons .

Comment: Better use `android.R.string.ok` and `android.R.string.cancel` instead of hard-coded strings "OK" and "Cancel"

Answer (score 92):

[Adding Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingButtons)

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MyActivity.this.finish();
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 13):

This should do the trick for you:

```
Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // call some other methods before that I guess...
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PasswActivity.this).create(); //Read Update
    alertDialog.setTitle("Uprgade");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Upgrade Text Here");
    alertDialog.setButton( Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Upgrade", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

       });

    alertDialog.setButton( Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

      });

    alertDialog.show();  //<-- See This!
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't you need to call `create()` **after** using the `AlertDialog.builder`'s setter methods to set up the `AlertDialog`?  If you don't, I don't think the options set will affect the dialog that's shown.

Answer (score 3):

```
btn_cancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(inflater.getContext());
        alert.setTitle("Do you want to Reject request");
        alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), "Rejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } });


        adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // finish();
            } });
        adb.show();
       // Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Please write what/how is your solution answer the question

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


adb.setView(alertDialogView);


adb.setTitle("Title of alert dialog");


adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);


adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        EditText et = (EditText)alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);


        Toast.makeText(Tutoriel18_Android.this, et.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } });


adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        finish();
  } });
adb.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alert dialog builder have an additional method called setButton2 and setButton3 which can also be used !

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Solution:

```
val alertDialog: AlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@ImageViewerActivity)
                                .create()

                        alertDialog.setTitle("Uprgade");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Upgrade Text Here");

                        alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Upgrade", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->


                        });
                        alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->


                        });
                        alertDialog.show();
```