# AlertDialog with CountDown Timer

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have definition below. This is AlertDialog with timer. I need add button, how do it properly? Method setButton is deprecated. Any Help?

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert 3");  
    alertDialog.setMessage("00:10");
    alertDialog.show();   // 

new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       alertDialog.setMessage("00:"+ (millisUntilFinished/1000));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Maybe this can help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227820/alert-dialog-two-buttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation

> Use setButton(int, CharSequence, Message) with BUTTON_POSITIVE.

Answer (score 1):

If you go throught [Alert Dialog Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html), you'll see that on `setButton()` says this :

> This method was deprecated in API level 3. Use setButton(int, CharSequence, Message) with BUTTON_POSITIVE.

So, the easiest way to add a button in an `Alert Dialog` is :

### Positive Button

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
     //Something you want to happen when user click
  }
});
```

### Negative Button

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //Something you want to happen when user click
    }
});
```

For more info, see [`setButton (CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setButton%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) documentation.