# How to add pop up option screen at start of app? Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, popup, popupwindow

I'm looking to have a window pop up at the very start of my android app with two options on it.

I have two functional buttons already in my app and I'd like the user to pick one of the two buttons before they get in to the app.

Lets say the screen pops up at launch and I'd like it to say "Please choose either 'button1' or 'button2'"

I've found a few solutions but none that I can actually get working...think that might be might novice status though.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a splash screen (many tutorials can be found on this, [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565) is an example). After having this activity, you can create a `Dialog` with 2 buttons (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227820/alert-dialog-two-buttons)).

You can set a positive and negative button on the dialog to do this, and also use a callback for the click behavior (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601049/adding-positive-negative-button-to-dialogfragments-dialog)).